# How to hide message popup if page have record rule don't have records odoo 15

Tags: record, odoo-15, record-rules

If i go to a page such as "Manufaturing", and this page have record rules, then if that page have records but not showing out because of record rule, it will show this message, how to prevent this to happen?

I've try to create a new record which is not affected by record rule, and the message is gone, and everything is back to normal, but i want this message not showing even if there's no records.

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't see the message suggests there are records. And since there are records the rules apply. You need to check the rules that are suggested in the message box and set the security rules accordingly. You need to check multi-company rules as it suggests.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? you mean i should check the record rule again?

Comment: Yes you should. Especially mult-company rules. I suggest, you keep giving more permission and keeping track of the changes and once you find the portion that needed to be given, than do the reverse and restore the unnecessary changes you have made.